# Why is usage of the typeid keyword bad design?

Tags: c++, typeid

I have heard a lot of people say any usage of `typeid` is bad design, yet to me it seems like it offers great utility.

1. When (and why) is usage of `typeid` "bad design"?
2. When is usage of `typeid` acceptable?
3. When it is not acceptable, but you still need something alike, what
   would an alternative be that would have good design?

Comment: Where did who say it's bad design?

Comment: @SethCarnegie I have heard some people say it on SO, and also read it in a book that type checking is bad design, yet no reason has been given.

Comment: That they gave no reason is probably an indication of the legitimacy of their claims. Some people do say that if you are doing a lot of type checking, you should refactor your code into polymorphic function calls. For instance, instead of doing `if (typeid(a) == atype) doa(); else if (typeid(a) == btype) dob(); else if (typeid(a) == ctype) doc();` you could just do `a->doafunc();` and the appropriate virtual function would be called for the runtime type of `a`.

Comment: Could you describe the cases where you think it is useful?

Comment: "good" and "bad" are subjective, you know...

Comment: @Seth: You are guilty of a classic *ad hominem* fallacy.  Just because a statement is made by a cargo cult programmer who can't explain it does not make the statement false.  It DOES make it suspect, but any unsupported statement is, regardless of source.  However, this claim is legitimate; see my answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt notice the _probably_. If there's one thing I am not guilty of, it's knowing everything. Also, it's not _ad hominem_ because I am not attacking the motives or character of any person, nor am I appealing to emotions rather than logic. The point of my comments is that nothing is ever "bad design" always and forever in and of itself. You can use something correctly or incorrectly but that's up to you, and there is no feature that should never ever ever be used. It annoys me when people use false massive blanket generalisations.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem isn't with `typeid`. The problem is that seeing `typeid` would encourage you to write this:

```
PolymorphicType *pType = ...;
if(typeid(*pType) == typeid(Derived1))
  pType->Func1();
else if(typeid(*pType) == typeid(Derived2))
  pType->Func2();
else if(typeid(*pType) == typeid(Derived3))
  pType->Func3();
```

This is what we call "really stupid". This is a virtual function call done in about the least reasonable way possible. `typeid` has the potential for abuse when used to replace `dynamic_cast` and `virtual` functions.

This example may sound far-fetched. After all, it's obvious that this is just a virtual call. But bad code often grows from the path of least resistance; all it takes is for one person to do a `typeid() == typeid()`, and the seed of this code has begin. In general, if you're directly using `typeid` frequently, odds are very good that you're doing something that could be better done with other language constructs.

`typeid` is the polymorphic type deduction method of *last* resort.

Is all usage of `typeid` wrong? Of course not. `boost::any` wouldn't be possible without it. Well it would be *possible,* but it wouldn't be any safer than `void*`. `typeid` is what makes type-safe `boost::any` type erasure possible. There are other legitimate uses of it.

But in code-lines-to-use ratio, I would suggest it should be in about one in 10,000 lines of code, at most. Much fewer than that, and you're probably using it wrong.

> Is type checking slow?

In general, the main reason to call `typeid` is either in templated code (as in `boost::any`) or when you're expecting a polymorphic type. If the type is statically determined (ie: a typename or value of a non-polymorphic type is given), then you can expect it to be done at compile-time.

It's polymorphic values you should be concerned about. I've seen a performance test that showed that some `typeid` implementations actually walk the class hierarchy, so the time it takes for them to find the type is proportional to the number of classes between the real type and the given type. Every implementation will be different, but that's a pretty good indication that maybe you shouldn't put it in performance-critical code.

Comment: `typeid(x).name()` is also quite handy for writing debugging/log statements.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide a link to where `boost::any` uses `typeid`?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't know where `boost::any`'s source code is online, but line 180 of `boost/any.hpp` in version 1.47 has it. Indeed, just searching that file will show several uses of it.

Comment: Hmmm, it's [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/any.hpp).  But that usage actually looks somewhat broken, you can't put in a `Derived` object and cast to `Base*`.  I'm guessing that's a limitation of `boost::any` purely because it's a deficiency of `typeid`, but it's hardly evidence that `typeid` is the "right" solution to the problem.

Comment: @BenVoigt: "But that usage actually looks somewhat broken, you can't put in a Derived object and cast to Base*." Broken is in the eye of the beholder. It's not legal to cast a `Derived*` to a `void*` then cast it to a `Base*`. So it's not legal to do that with `boost::any` either. To me, this is `boost::any` doing its job: you get back *exactly and only* what you put into it.

Comment: @NicolBolas , I don't want to look "really stupid", but I didn't quite get your example. Is it pType->Func() that should be used instead of the code you provided? If not, could you please specify it more clearly for me? Thank you.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y, I was doing exactly that right now and was wondering if it is a good idea or not. `:)`

Answer (score 7):

I don't think anyone says that usage of `typeid` is itself bad design; rather, what you'll hear is that usage of `typeid` is *indicative* of bad design. The idea there is that any logic that distinguishes (say) `Square` from `Circle` should actually be *in* those classes, so should be expressed by a virtual function (polymorphism).

Needless to say, this is not an absolute rule.

Comment: And performance wise, are there any reasons? Is type checking slow?

Comment: @xcrypt unless the operand of `typeid` is a polymorphic type, `typeid` is done at compile time. If the operand is a polymorphic type, how fast or slow it is depends on how the compiler writers implemented it. If they implemented it by making the program send the text of your program to a company employee and have him type the type of the class back to the program, then it will be slow.

Comment: @SethCarnegie who would do such a thing? :p

Comment: @xcrypt: As Seth Carnegie says, it depends on the implementation; but broadly speaking, I would not expect the performance of `typeid` to differ greatly from that the use of virtual functions. So this is a software engineering issue, not a performance issue.

Answer (score 6):

It's too bad that those who gave you this good advice couldn't give the reasons for it.  It means they're simple [cargo cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult) programmers.

All expressions have a static compile-time type (after template expansion).  All types are either polymorphic or not.

I'll try to elaborate for you why `typeid` is (the closest thing to) useless in both cases:

1. There is no reason to use `typeid` when the expression's static type is not polymorphic.  The compiler will use the static type, not the dynamic type, so compile-time function overloading works.  And type identity can be checked much more efficiently using a templated type trait such as `is_same`.
2. If the static type of the expression is polymorphic, then `typeid` fails.  Yes, it will give information on the dynamic type of the object.  But only the most derived dynamic type.  This violates the Liskov Substitution Principle, since given types `Base` and `Child`, adding a new type `Grandchild` derived from `Child` will not be treated as `Child` is.  The Open-Closed principle is also violated, since the design cannot be extended with new types without rewriting everything.  There is no encapsulation, since information about the class hierarchy must be scattered throughout the program, creating strong coupling.  `dynamic_cast` overcomes some but not all of these problems.

In short, a program that uses `typeid` will be very difficult to maintain and test.

And, as with any rule, there may be limited exception.  Where you're using OO language features of inheritance and virtual functions, but you don't actually want a polymorphic design.  I can think of exactly one: where you want to log the name of the type as a string, using `type_info::name()`.  You might also be able to use it to detect slicing (where polymorphism is already violated).  But this is good for debugging only, never for controlling program flow.

Comment: "There is no reason to use typeid when the expression's static type is not polymorphic." Unless you're writing `boost::any`, and you want to provide assurance to the user that the static type they shoved into the variable is the same one they're trying to cast out of it. You know, 99% of the point of `boost::any`.

Comment: @Nicol: IMO, that's one of the debugging uses, and `any_cast` isn't even handling types correctly to begin with.  All the problems with `typeid` carry over to `boost::any`, and as a result programs using `boost::any` are difficult to maintain and test.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `boost::any` is a type-safe `void*`. It's *job* is to ensure that the person who put something into the `any` and the person who took something out of the `any` agree on what that something is, so as not to violate C++ and cause undefined behavior. There's nothing "difficult to maintain and test" about this; what you put in is what you get out. "Liskov Substitution" and "Open-Closed" are *irrelevant* in this context. Of course there's strong coupling, but *that's what you asked for* when you decided to use type erasure. At least it's *safe* strong coupling.

Comment: @Nicol: But you do lose maintainability when you have strong coupling and violate SOLID.  And unless the comments are exceptionally good, using inheritance in a way that doesn't line up with LSP is going to confuse future developers who are familiar with OOP.  And while `boost::any` may prevent unsafe operations, it also forbids upcasting which is theoretically correct.  To say that `void*` acts the same way is pointless, since `void*` doesn't have the desired semantics to begin with.

Comment: `void*`s semantics *are* the desired semantics for `any`. In general, you use `any` because you cannot pass a fully typed object through a particular place. Generic message and signals, for example. In that case, you simply accept the delocalized coupling because the benefits (being able to actually *work*) outweigh the downsides (the possibility of getting an any_cast exception). It's great to live in the SOLID ivory tower and everything, but sometimes you have to do the not-so-nice things and accept the increased maintenance price. It's good to have `any` there to make the maintenance easier

Comment: @Nicol: From that perspective, `boost::any` is simply a `void*` plus an debug check.  And debugging is where I said `typeid` can be helpful.  It's the case I mentioned "where polymorphism is already violated".