# c++ how to sort a vector by class type

Tags: c++, class, sorting, vector

I have a base class of "mediaInfo" with three derived classes of "Book" "Video" and "Music". In my main file I have a vector declared as type "mediaInfo" which dynamically allocates memory and assigns a vector element to either type "mediaInfo" "Book" "Video" or "Music" dependent on the input from a test script. Another functionality of the code is to sort the vector elements by type (Book, Video, Music, mediaInfo), name, and media value. I have name down and am struggling with how to sort by type. I can provide code if needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

add a virtual method to MediaInfo to provide rank information. eg:

```
class MediaInfo {
public:
    virtual int rank() = 0;
};

class Book : MediaInfo {
public:
    virtual int rank() { return 100; }
};

class Video : MediaInfo {
public:
    virtual int rank() { return 200; }
};
```

then you can sort by `obj->rank()` and other information;

Comment: This is a very good solution but note it makes `MediaInfo` abstract so it can't be instantiated. You could fix that (if need be) by using just a virtual function for rank and not a pure virtual function in the `MediaInfo` class.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++98 there is an `operator` called `typeid`, you can use that.
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int i;
  cout << typeid(i).name();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:
`int`
You can take any data type not just built-in.

Comment: Actually it's not a method and it's there since C++98.

Answer (score 1):

While I have seen it discouraged, another (technically) valid way to sort would be the use of typeid. Quick example:

```
std::vector<MediaInfo*> list;
list.push_back(new Book());
list.push_back(new Video());
list.push_back(new Book());
list.push_back(new MediaInfo());

std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), [](MediaInfo* a, MediaInfo* b){ 
    return typeid(*a).hash_code() < typeid(*b).hash_code(); 
});
```

That being said, a virtual method as mentioned in the other answer is probably a better way to implement it.
More information on the pitfalls of typeid can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547577/651630)

Comment: Will the generated hash_code be according to the lexicographic order of the typename, or something else?

Comment: @GargAnkit I believe the return value of hash_code is left unspecified (There's a bit more information [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code)). However, if lexicographic order is important, you could just as easily sort by typeid(someObject).name(). But again, the return value is compiler specific.