# C++ Vastly Different Derived Classes - Virtual methods? A cast?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I have a class hierarchy with lots of shared member functions in a base class, and also a large number of unique member functions in two derived classes:

```
    class Scene {
    public:
        void Display();
        void CreateDefaultShapes();
        void AddShape(Shape myShape);
        // lots more shared member functions
    }

    Class AnimatedScene : public Scene {
    public:
        void SetupAnimation();
        void ChangeAnimationSpeed(float x, float y);
        // lots of member functions unique to animation
    }

    Class ControllableScene : public Scene {
    public:
        void ConfigureControls();
        void MoveCamera(float x, float y, float z);
        void Rotate(float x, float y, float z);
        // lots of member functions unique to a controllable scene
    }
```

Not surprisingly, this doesn't work:

```
    Scene myScene;
    myScene.SetupAnimation();
```

What is the correct solution to this problem? Should I make all of the derived member functions virtual and add them to the base? Should I use a cast when calling `SetupAnimation()`? Is there a more clever design that solves this problem?

Note: I receive `myScene` from elsewhere and can't simply declare it as `AnimatedScene` when I instantiate it.

Edit: I've added a couple more member functions to illustrate the point. A small handful of initialization functions definitely lend themselves to simply using `virtual`.

Comment: Why would you want to call `setupAnimation` if you don't know for sure that the object is of the correct type?

Comment: If you are sure myScene is an AnimatedScene object, you can cast it to the AnimatedScene type like: ((AnimatedScene*)myScene)->SetupAnimation();

Comment: I am certain that `myScene` is an `AnimatedScene` in the places in the code that `SetupAnimation()` gets called. A C-Style cast (AnimatedScene *) would work, but I've read that this is not advised in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar problem in my compiler project, where the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) is constructed from the statements, so `while(x != 0) { if (a == b) x = 0; }` would construct a `whileAST` with a `binaryExpr` inside it, then a `blockAST` with the `ifAST`, and so on. Each of these have some common properties, and a lot of things that only apply when you actually do something specific to that part. Most of the time, that is solved by calling a generic (virtual) member function.

However, SOMETIMES you need to do very specific things. There are two ways to do that:

- use `dynamic_cast` (or `typeid` + `reinterpret_cast` or `static cast`).
- Set up dozens of `virtual` member functions, which mostly are completely useless (doesn't do anything or return an "can't do that" indication of some sort)

In my case, I choose the first one. It shouldn't be the common case, but sometimes it is indeed the right thing to do.

So in this case, you'd do something like:

```
AnimatedScene *animScene = dynamic_cast<AnimatedScene*>(&scene);
if (!animScene) 
{ 
   ... do something else, since it's not an AnimatedScene ...
}
animScene->SetupAnimation();
```

Comment: It sounds like there's no magic bullet here and I need to choose one of these approaches. As Dominic suggested, I think I also need to re-examine my design.

Answer (score 1):

- You can cast it, preferably using `static_cast`. The least preferable option. If you are casting things, it usually means your design needs more thought
- If you have a particular function/class that needs one or the other, declare the input as the type you need, which more accurately communicates the requirements of the function or class
- If the function needs to be generic, and those methods don't require any input, then you could define a virtual method in the parent class, say `init`, which in the derived classes call the correct methods to set up the instance.

Comment: Solution 2 makes a lot of sense, but these functions get called from the GUI and they access the myScene member of a Canvas class so there's no opportunity to declare the input.

Comment: @Arpyzo, it's hard to give advice when you haven't given the complete context. It sounds like you need to make them more generic and really think about the operations that all of the derived classes share, and that the functions require to be able to be called, and then make a generic interface to that. IE the third dot point above.

Comment: Sometimes it is really hard to be completely generic and you have to cast. The danger there is that you will actually have an incompatible type, and the bugs you will get will be bizarre and hard to track down. Don't use C style IE (Type)variable. They do multiple styles of cast and might not do the right thing. static_cast is for when you are really sure you know what the true type of the object is, and there is dynamic_cast which is safer, but has an overhead. If you can't afford that overhead, a simple check like a virtual getType function in the parent to check before you cast is advised.

Answer (score 0):

I am not yet able to comment, which is what I really wanted to do, but I am also interested in figuring this out as well.

A few months ago I had a similar problem. What I can tell you is that you can use typeid operator to figure out what type the object is, like so:

```
int main()
{

    scene* ptr = new AnimatedScene();
    if (typeid(*ptr) == typeid(AnimatedScene))
    {
        cout<<"ptr is indeed a animatedScene"<<endl;
        AnimatedScene* ptr2 = (AnimatedScene*)(ptr);
        ptr2->SetupAnimation();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"not a animatedscene!!!"<<endl;
    }

}
```

This works, you'll then be able to use ptr2 to access the animatedScene's unique members.

Notice the use of pointers, you can't use the objects directly, due to something called "object slicing" when playing with polymorphism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing

Like you I have heard something about the use of typeid and thus, casting being a bad idea, but as to why, I cannot tell you. I am hoping to have a more experienced programmer explain it.

What I can tell you is that this works without problems in this simple example, you've avoided the problem of declaring meaningless virtual functions in the basetype.

Edit: It's amazing how often I forget to use google: [Why is usage of the typeid keyword bad design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547375/why-is-usage-of-the-typeid-keyword-bad-design)

If I understand mr Bolas correctly, typeid incentivizes bad coding practices. However, in your example you want to access a subtypes non-virtual function. As far as I know, there is no way of doing that without checking type at compiletime, ie typeid.

Answer (score 0):

If such problem arises with your hierarchy that proves that hierarchy was too generalized. You might want to implement interfaces pattern, if class have certain functionality, it would inherit an interface that defines that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Proven that dogs are animals, do all animal but dogs fail to bark, or do only dogs bark?

The first approach lead to a `class animal` failing all the verses of the entire zoo, implemented one-by one in each animal. And in particular `class dog` will override just `bark()`.
In this approach animal becomes a sort of "god object" (knows everything), requiring to be constantly updated every time something new is introduced, and requiring It's entire "universe" to be re-created (recompile everything) after it.

The second approach requires first to check the animal is a dog (via `dynamic cast`) and then ask it to bark. (or check for `cat` before asking a `mieow`)

The trade-off will probably consist in understanding how frequent is the possibility you have to check a bark out of its context (not knowing which animal are you deal with), how to report a fail, and what to do in case of such fail.

In other words, **the key driver is not the bark, but the context around it** inside your program.

Comment: in case of interface bark() would be a feature of barking_animal interface, same thing , but it may exist in parallel to global hierarchy and applay not only to dogs (because they aren't only ones who bark)

Comment: Now model a complete zoo that way without go crazy and without re-typing implementations...  and you will reinvent tag dispatching.  And anyhow .. animal has all the interfaces (god object once again) or it has none and you query for it, reinventing dynamic cast.

Comment: Depends on implementation, and who said about reinvention? dynamic_cast  _would_ be the query, because interface is the class of the object usually. Alternative is adapter interface which often is confusing too. Nearly every pattern in hierarchy design may end with god objects if taken , it depends on objective. C++ got limited tagging  capabilities after all, so many real-life frameworks extend it anyway, at least for inner working.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Are you trying to do something like this?
class Scene{
public:
    virtual void Display()=0; //Pure virtual func
};

class AnimatedScene : public Scene{
public:
    void Display(){
        std::cout<<"function Display() inside class AnimatedScene"    <<std::endl;
    }
};

class ControllableScene : public Scene{
public:
    void Display(){
        std::cout<<"function Display() inside class ControllableScene"  <<std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    AnimatedScene as;
    ControllableScene cs;

    Scene *ex1 = &as;
    Scene *ex2 = &cs;

    ex1->Display();
    ex2->Display();

    return 0;
}
```